# getting disk space through python. IF statement not picking up value

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script in python that get's the percentage value of the used disk space.
I do this by running the df -h command through subprocess and then storing the value in the diskspace var.

Later on when i use it in my IF Statement it seems like it's not properly picking up the value.

The disk space percentage is 76. I set the IF statement to trigger an e-mail and print a message if the percentage is higher than 90. But eventhough the value is lower it still triggers the e-mail and prints the message in the IF.

I guess it has to do with the fact that the output i get in python isn't simply a integer value of 76 but rather ('76\n', None) so it sees this as a string value ?

Does anybody have a suggestion ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import smtplib
import socket
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

hostname = socket.gethostname()
me = 'user@gmail.com'
you = ['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'd@gmail.com']

getdiskspace = "df -k / | awk 'NR > 1 {sub( \"%\", \"\", $5); print $5 }'"
proc = subprocess.Popen(getdiskspace, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
diskspace = proc.communicate()

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Disk space getting full ' + hostname
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ", ".join(you)
msg['X-Priority'] = '1'
msg['X-MSMail-Priority'] = 'High'

text = "Disk space getting full on the " + hostname
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
       Diskspace is getting full on one of the servers, go check it out.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", "587")
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('user@gmail.com', 'MYPASS')

if (diskspace > 90):
        print('This is not ok, load is ' + repr(diskspace))
        server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()

else:
        print('this is ok.')
```

Comment: You're getting a tuple.  You want the first value as an integer.  `diskspace = int(diskspace[0])`.

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to check the value as soon as you retrieve it, rather than to create an email message and then maybe don't send it.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try that out once i get back behind a terminal !

Comment: @g.d.d.c That worked ! Thank you very much.